# Group by time interval including start of next?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I'm trying to build a query that groups my data by a timed interval (i.e. 30 minutes) and then calculate the difference between the first and last row in each group.

`select (max(v) - min(v)) as x, from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d)/(30*60))*(30*60)) as timeKey from y group by timeKey`

The above correctly returns my data in 30 minute chunks however I need to somehow tweak it to include everything between `12:00 and 12:30` rather than `12:00 and 12:29`.

I had attempted to use the following however `max` can't be used when assigning a value.

`` select max(v) - @lastV, from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d)/(30*60))*(30*60)) as timeKey, @lastv := v from `test`, (select @lastV:=0) lastV group by timeKey ``

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8d74/4

I've created the above SQL Fiddle with some data that can be used as an example.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Then you'll get duplicate entries . `12:30` will be both in `12:00-12:30` and `12:30 - 13:00` . In which one of them you want it ?

Comment: @sagi - sorry, feel I hadn't responded appropriately - I'm trying to replicate a  process currently handled via code, which loops through intervals and performs a query i.e. `(select max(v) - min(v) as usage from 'test' where d between '2016-01-01 12:00' and '2016-01-01 12:30'`. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution that I managed to come up with this morning:

`` select *, IF(@lastV, @lastV - minV, 0) as `usage`, @lastV := minV from (
    select min(v) as minV, max(v) as maxV, from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d)/(30*60))*(30*60)) as timeKey from `test` group by timeKey order by timeKey desc
) items, (select @lastV:=0) lastV ``

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8d74/18/0

It unfortunately only works when sorting descending and produces a redundant row (first row has nothing to compare to) however based on my tests, this row isn't required and can be ignored when reading the data.

Would be useful if anyone had any other solutions?